# Convert int to double

Tags: c, printf

I ran this simple program, but when I convert from `int` to `double`, the result is zero.  The `sqrt` of the zeros then displays negative values.  This is an example from an online tutorial so I'm not sure why this is happening. I tried in Windows and Unix.

```
/* Hello World program */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

main()

{  int i;

   printf("\t Number \t\t Square Root of Number\n\n");

   for (i=0; i<=360; ++i)
        printf("\t %d \t\t\t %d \n",i, sqrt((double) i));


}
```

Comment: sqrt never returns negative values. Your problems run very deep. The fact that you don't realise that we would need to see your code to answer this is your fundamental problem. I hope you don't think that the computer can do the same!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is incorrect use of printf format - use %g/%f instead of %d

BTW - if you are wondering what your code did here is some abridged explanation that may help you in understanding:

printf routine has treated your floating point result of sqrt as integer. Signed, unsigned integers have their underlying bit representations (put simply - it's the way how they are 'encoded' in memory, registers etc). By specifying format to printf you tell it how it should decipher that bit pattern in specific memory area/register (depends on calling conventions etc). For example:

```
unsigned int myInt = 0xFFFFFFFF;
printf( "as signed=[%i] as unsigned=[%u]\n", myInt, myInt );
```

gives: "as signed=[-1] as unsigned=[4294967295]"

One bit pattern used but treated as signed first and unsigned later. Same applies to your code. You've told printf to treat bit pattern that was used to 'encode' floating point result of sqrt as integer. See this:

```
float myFloat = 8.0;
printf( "%08X\n", *((unsigned int*)&myFloat) );
```

prints: "41000000"

According to [single precision floating point encoding format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985).
8.0 is simply (-1)^0*(1+fraction=0)*2^(exp=130-127)=2*3=8.0 but printed as int looks like just 41000000 (hex of course).

Comment: Thank you. Strange that this would go unnoticed on a tutorial.  I used %f and it works fine now.

Comment: The tutorial would not have used %d for a floating point value

Comment: @David: Have you really never seen a tutorial, book etc without a single typo/bug? It happens - really.

Answer (score 20):

Maybe this?

```
int number;
double dblNumber = (double)number;
```

Comment: This is, indeed, how one converts a number to a double, but that's not the asker's issue.

Comment: Oddly, the title of his question was.  Oh well.

Comment: No need to add the cast `(double)` as you've already annotated the type and the compiler will implicitly do the cast. Alternatively, you could just change the type annotation to `auto dblNumber = (double)number;`, this way you don't have to "maintain" the type in two places (in case you want to change it to say a `float` later).

Comment: @MichaelHall Are you sure about the `auto` thing?

Comment: @MehdiCharife yes I am. You could try it yourself if you need convincing...https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3zn32y6v5

Comment: @MichaelHall The question is about C, not C++.

Comment: Good point @MehdiCharife - I missed that distinction. I can't seem to edit my comment anymore though unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

`sqrt()` return a value of type `double`. You cannot print such a value with the conversion specifier `"%d"`.

Try one of these two alternatives

```
        printf("\t %d \t\t\t %f \n",i, sqrt(i)); /* use "%f" */
        printf("\t %d \t\t\t %d \n",i, (int)sqrt(i)); /* cast to int */
```

---

The `i` argument to `sqrt()` is converted to double implicitly, as long as there is a prototype in scope. Since you included the proper header, there is no need for an explicit conversion.

Comment: I do not understand why it works with to give an `int` to `sqrt()` tough, because `sqrt()` is declared as to only take a `double` value as an argument. In C99: `double sqrt (double x);` How does that work and my compiler let it pass?

Comment: @RobertS: Because you included `<math.h>` the compiler knows the argument to `sqrt()` must be `double`, so the compiler does the conversion automatically. Using `sqrt()` (or any function really) without a prototype in scope should be considered an error.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also posted a question about this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59310504/sqrt-why-am-i-allowed-to-provide-an-argument-of-int-and-not-only-double-and . If you want an upvote plus for your answer, which i like to give, you can post your answer also there and make it also available to read for others who have the same issue.