# Assignment of a large value to int variable in C

Tags: c

I know that overflow happens when I assign a value larger than `INT_MAX` to an int variable, but what happens if this value is divided by a large number too? in the following statement
`int x = 3000000000/10000;` will overflow happen?

Comment: There is no overflow if you assign `INT_MAX` to `int`

Comment: The maximum value of an `int` (if 32-bits) is `2147483647`.  This may be undefined behavior if `3000000000` is converted to an `int`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits It is rather implementation defined.

Comment: @EugeneSh. exactly as how constant expression 3000000000/10000 will be calculated by the compiler is up to implementation. I do not know is standard says something about it.

Comment: @P__J__ It is actually well defined. The constants will get types as defined [in this table](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5) (so yeah, will depend on the size of the types) and will be followed by [usual arithmetic conversions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I do not know. This example contradicts it https://godbolt.org/z/zKqhWM Explicit conversion is needed.

Comment: @P__J__ Not sure why you are saying it is required? Adding the cast as in your example is rather making it implementation defined (you are converting a value that cannot fit the target type into a signed type). Without the cast it is behaving exactly according to the two standard sections I cited.

Comment: @EugeneSh. IMO 30000000000 compiler should convert to int (as it is int constant - no `l` or `ll` suffix), then divide by the 100000.

Comment: @P__J__ According to the [table](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5) if no suffix is provided -  it will be converted to `long int` if not fitting into `int`. Or `long long int` if not fitting that too.

Comment: @EugeneSh.   plus +

Answer (score 3):

If the integer constants (literals) in an expression are representable in types supported by the C compiler, with the correct signedness, the compiler will perform correct arithmetic (as defined by the C standard) on them. If the result can be represented in an `int`, then `int x = expression;` will initialize `x` to have that value.

If the result cannot be represented in an `int`, then the result of the initialization is implementation-defined, per C 2018 6.3.1.3 3.

If an integer constant is not representable in any type, with the correct signedness, supported by the C compiler, then the behavior is not defined by the C standard, except that the compiler must provide a diagnostic message (per 6.4.4.1 6 and 6.4.4 3).

Answer (score 0):

You could cast larger numbers as e.g.  `long long` and then cast the result back to int. That should avoid any overflow.
So like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9047811
(Only that you would cast it back to int afterwards by `int result = (int)((long long)(numerator)/(long long)(denominator))`.

Comment: `long long` would be much better than `double`

Comment: Alternatively add LL at the end of the number

Answer (score 0):

> I know that overflow happens when I assign a value larger than INT_MAX to an int variable,

*Overflow* does not occur when the constant is within `(unsigned) long long`.  Instead this is a *conversion* of a value out of range of an `int`.  The result is *implementation defined*.

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
> ...
> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised. C17dr 6.3.1.3

A common *implementation defined behavior* is to lop off upper bits.

```
int some_int = 0x123456789A;  // Out of range
printf("%d\n"); --> possible outcome 0x3456789A as "878082202"
```

---

> what happens if this value is divided by a large number too? will overflow happen?

No. `3000000000` in this case is a `long` or `long long`.  The quotient is the same type, but of value 300,000.  With a 32-bit `int`, that converts nicely to a `int` with a value of 300,000.

```
int x = 3000000000/10000;
```

Appending an `LL` in `int x = 3000000000LL/10000;` makes not difference in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In your *specific* case:

```
int x = 3000000000/10000;
```

The right side expression is a constant, so the compiler [`gcc`, at least], resolves the division at compile time, so the result is `300000`. (To do that, the compiler has to do the constant reduction using higher precision than `int` internally)

But, if you do:

```
int x = 3000000000;
x /= 10000;
```

You get: `-129496` [hence overflow]

That's because `x` got an overflow [and became negative] on the first line.

`3000000000` still fits in 32 bits (*unsigned*), so you get the value `0x0xb2d05e00`. Note the MSB [sign bit] is set.

And, when you divide by `10000`, the division will preserve the sign and produce: `0xfffe0628`

The two code snippets, *at first glance*, should produce the same result. But, they don't because the compiler has to honor the two step process (i.e. it can't combine the two steps together).

Otherwise, the compiler would break other code that relies on truncation, etc: (e.g. rounding):

```
int x = 37;
x /= 10;
x *= 10;
```

You lucked out because `3000000000` [as I said] fits in `unsigned int`. But, if you add an extra 0 (e.g.) `30000000000`, the compiler will flag it:

```
warning: overflow in conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘int’ changes value from ‘30000000000’ to ‘-64771072’ [-Woverflow]
  int x = 30000000000;
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

So, you really shouldn't rely on a specific result, *if* you already know you're doing something that is questionable/wrong.

---

Here's a sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
print_x(void)
{
    int x = 3000000000/10000;

    return x;
}

int
print_y(void)
{
    int y = 3000000000;

    y /= 10000;

    return y;
}

int
print_z(void)
{
    int z = 3000000000;

    return z;
}

int
print_w(void)
{
    int w = 30000000000;

    return w;
}

int
main(void)
{

    printf("x=%d\n",print_x());
    printf("y=%d\n",print_y());
    printf("z=%d\n",print_z());
    printf("w=%d\n",print_w());

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the program output:

```
x=300000
y=-129496
z=-1294967296
w=-64771072
```

Comment: Since C99, "3000000000 still fits in 32 bits (unsigned)" is true, but the constant is not of type `int` nor `unsigned`.  It is at least `long`, if not `long long`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Personally, I didn't think it was UB [just that you'd get a truncated result], but some of the top comments suggested otherwise, so, _mea culpa_, I caved a bit. I've removed the UB language from my answer, and added some explanation.